# jQuery method .on() on dynamically(AJAX) loaded data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i have a page in my site that has a  with class name 'mainContent' that automatically updates with new data every like 1 minute using AJAX .ajax(). Content in this  requires some JavaScript for some functionalities. The problem now is that JavaScript does not work on the new data loaded into the DOM without whole page refresh. I have searched and found using .on() to bind the data to the DOM should work, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mainContent',function(){
        expand();
    });
```

where expand is a JS function.
However, it only works fully on the new data but not on the data that had been added in the previous AJAX call...

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: What means "it only works"? Is function called for new elements? Why do you think it's not?

Comment: Yap, function is only called for new elements that were loaded on the last AJAX call...

Comment: A jsfiddle would help us help you.

Comment: Please post the markup and any more relevant code.  The new data that is added, does each item have the class `mainContent`?

Comment: @Denny: how do you know it's only called for new elements? What if you put `alert('it is called everytime');` in the function body?

Comment: I bet you just have incorrect `expand()` implementation (since I don't see how you determine which element to expand)

Comment: @zerkms coz immediately after the AJAX call, the new data can be expanded but the older data in the page does not expand the way it should.

Comment: function expand(){
            $('.expander').simpleexpand();
        };

Comment: @Denny: "coz immediately after the AJAX call, the new data can be expanded but the older data" --- it doesn't mean that function isn't called. If you put `alert('listen to zerkms and stop guessing');` as first line to the `expand()` function implementation you'll see I'm right. And it means that your function and/or plugin implemented incorrectly.

Comment: Please, update your question and add some of your markup. It's hard to understand what's going on there

Comment: Well, @zerkms,iit doesnt happen coz the alert pops up when i click on the new data from the last AJAX call after i changed my code to this...$('.mainContent').on('click', 'a', function(){
  expand(); and changed the function to: function expand(){
  alert('Im here')
            $('.expander').simpleexpand();
        };
 });

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, it's just your logic. This is how this jQuery function works:

1. You set a **container**. This is the element that will hold the AJAX-crated items that you want to bind. The more specific, the better. Otherwise, you'll wire an event for your whole page, which is bad
2. The **event**. What are you listening to?
3. Who will fire the handler. A selector to form the phrase: when **these guys** inside **this big guy** fire **this event**, run **this code**.

Let's suppose that your `mainContent` gets filled with hyperlinks (I'm not sure because your question lacks on details):

```
$('.mainContent').on('click', 'a', function () {
  //do your magic
  //$(this) is the clicked link
});
```

This way, our phrase is: when **links** inside **.mainContent** are **clicked**, run **this**.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments, I think that your problem may be on the `expand` function.
Let's give a try:

```
$('.mainContent').on('click', 'a', function () {
  $(this).simpleexpand();
});
```

Comment: Well, it seems there was a problem with the jQuery expander plugin...Thanx for your great help guys, learnt alot from all of u...

Comment: @Denny Don't forget to upvote answers that deserve it and to add your final answer so the question does not remain pending.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to apply your binding on the callback of the ajax function that load your new datas ?

Something like that :

```
$.ajax({
  url: url...//Classic ajax call
}).done(function ( data ) {

    //Apply your 'on' here

});
```

Comment: The whole point of event delegation is to not have to do this.